# Java program "freezes shortly"

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I am new at java and its not my first programming language.
I actually try to code a downloader which downloads all files until the version on the server is the same as the client ones.

The program runs good but the is a thing i cant solve.

If i run this code :

```
private void updateContent()
{
    DownloadButton.setEnabled(false);
    SaveLocationButton.setEnabled(false);
    UpdateText.setText("Update to Version " + ServerVersionNumber + "...");
    UpdateText.setForeground(new Color(200, 150, 0, 255));
    ProgressText.setText("(1/2) Files will be downloaded");
    ProgressText.setForeground(new Color(200, 150, 0, 255));
    LoadingBar.setStringPainted(true);

    for(int i = 1; i < (ServerVersionNumber - LocalVersionNumber + 1); i++)
    {
        int CurrentUpdateFile = LocalVersionNumber + i;


        try 
        {
            URL FileURL = new URL(Host + CurrentUpdateFile + ".zip");

            try {
                FileURL.openConnection();


                InputStream reader = FileURL.openStream();
                FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(ContentSaveDirectory + CurrentUpdateFile + ".zip");

                byte[] buffer = new byte[153600];
                int bytesRead = 0;


                while ((bytesRead = reader.read(buffer)) > 0)
                {  
                    writer.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    buffer = new byte[153600];
                }

                writer.close();
                reader.close();

            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

all things like `DownloadButton.setEnabled(false);` and a few lines under will be changed after all file are downloaded could anyone say me why?

Comment: It would be better if you followed Java coding conventions to begin with; for one, variable names should begin with a lower case letter. You seem to be doing this in some places but not others, which is all the more confusing :/

Comment: Also, what version of Java is that?

Comment: OK, first remarks: no need for `openConnection()` before `openStream()`; then: all resources should be closed in a `finally` block, here you close them in `try`; "finally", you can easily have one level indentation less if you attempt to create URLs before you attempt to read them (for `MalformedURLException`).

Comment: you need our friend [THREADS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616109/Java-Thread-Tutorial) for each fetching (or at least one thread for downloads), and another for gui handlers

Comment: What do you mean "all things like `DownloadButton.setEnabled(false);` and a few lines under will be changed"? What do they change to?

Comment: `153600`? Why this number? It is convention to use `1024` as that represents a single kilobyte.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are calling this method from an event handler, it is executed in the event dispatch thread, and the download blocks repaints and event handling. On the other hand, updates to the GUI should be done only from the event dispatch thread. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

The simplest fix is starting a new thread for the download, like below. For better integration with the GUI, like updating it when the download completes, refer to the tutorial.

```
private void updateContent()
{
    DownloadButton.setEnabled(false);
    SaveLocationButton.setEnabled(false);
    UpdateText.setText("Update to Version " + ServerVersionNumber + "...");
    UpdateText.setForeground(new Color(200, 150, 0, 255));
    ProgressText.setText("(1/2) Files will be downloaded");
    ProgressText.setForeground(new Color(200, 150, 0, 255));
    LoadingBar.setStringPainted(true);

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 1; i < (ServerVersionNumber - LocalVersionNumber + 1); i++)
            {
                // the rest
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```